# How to lace up a mishapen brooks?

Tags: saddle, leather

I have a brooks saddle that has bedded in, slightly out of alignment so that one side is lower than the other. I have heard that it is possible to 'lace up' the saddle in order to retain its shape? How do I do this, and is it advisable?

Comment: Might help: http://www.bikeforums.net/archive/index.php/t-148421.html, http://www.twowheelblogs.com/unit/tortured-and-tied-brutalized-brooks-saddle, http://www.flickr.com/groups/brookssaddles/discuss/72157619231337301/

Comment: See related question http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/12983/why-are-some-leather-saddles-laced-at-the-bottom-and-should-i-do-this-to-mine

Comment: What does it cost to try?

Comment: I know a guy whose Brooks saddle became quite out of alignment with use. Turns out he had [scoliosis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scoliosis) and never realised until he showed his saddle to a doctor friend.

Comment: What happened in the end?  Did you try lacing the saddle - how did it work out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You usually can only lace a leather saddle when it becomes sunken in the middle. Lacing the bottom across underneath will tighten up the sagging middle. This wouldn't likely be a "do it yourself" project without the proper tools/equipment. From your description, it sounds as if you're sitting on the saddle off to one side. I'm not sure this could be corrected by lacing. If you've had the Brooks saddle less than two years, then it should be covered under warranty if there is a problem with the leather itself or the seat frame construction that allowed this to happen. You'd need your receipt and return it to the dealer where you purchased it. It the saddle isn't under warranty, I'd suggest you take it to a horse tack shop in the area and see if they could straighten it up, reinforce the bottom and punch holes at a proper spacing to lace it up for you. Here's a link about the Brooks warranty, just in case.

http://www.brooksengland.com/getting-in-touch/contact-forms/info-request/warranty-claim/